# How to draw a 9 patch button in Qt?

Tags: qt, button, nine-patch

I want to draw a 9 patch button in Qt. Are there any working opensource implementations?

Advice please some general techniques how to implement it with the Qt image manipulation tools.

Comment: What's wrong with QPushButton?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/Roninsc2/NinePatchQt) library. It supports content area and multiple resize areas.

Answer (score 0):

The [`BorderImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html) QML type looks like it does what you need.