# How to use 9 patch png images on QML?

Tags: qt, qml, nine-patch

I'm making user interface using QML.

I was asked to use 9.png image files for this UI.

The size of this image is 82X94 pixels and I have to use this image for 1280X92 background.

I wrote the source code below.

```
Image {
    id: bgMode
    x: 0; y: 0
    width: 1280; height: 92
    source: "qrc:/res/img/bg_mode.9.png"
}
```

However, this code breaks the image while stretching it vertically.

I'm supposed to stretch the image without making it like slimy dough.

I thought there would be some program which edits 9 patch image files.

So I googled and found [this](http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/).

Hoever, I couldn't run this program using JRE.

The error message says it cannot find 'com.alee.extended.ninepatch.NinePatchEditorFrame'.

I gave up using this program here.

I googled if QML supports 9 patch image.

[Image Style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-imagine.html#9-patch-images) type seems relevant, but I couldn't figure out how to actually use it.

[This stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753703/how-to-draw-a-9-patch-button-in-qt) recommends BorderImage type. So I wrote source code below.

```
BorderImage {
        id: bgMode
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 1280; height: 92
        verticalTileMode: BorderImage.Round
        horizontalTileMode: BorderImage.Stretch
        border.left: 1; border.right: 1
        source: "qrc:/res/img/bg_mode.9.png"
}
```

But this code still breaks the image.

How to use 9 patch images on QML?

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, including the image and what the desired result should be. "breaks the image" is vague. 1px border for a 1280px image seems strange... and nothing for top/bottom borders?

Comment: @MaximPaperno Honestly I do not understand what thos left, right borders mean.

Comment: Well all the more reason to post your image and what you're trying to display it in. The whole bit about the image editor seems irrelevant. If you don't know what the borders mean, after reading the docs, I'm not sure you understand how a 9-patch image is supposed to be used in the first place. Is this the case? And elaborate on "I was asked to use 9.png image files for this UI." What UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Qt documentation page you have very good explanation. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html
The only thing you need to know is where those 2 vertical and two horizontal lines are placed (distance from the edge of the image).

```
border { left: 30; top: 30; right: 30; bottom: 30 }
```

Image will be spitted into 9 regions. If you do not want to stretched them horizontally but repeat use `horizontalTileMode: BorderImage.Repeat` property. Other modes are listed here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html#horizontalTileMode-prop